# 'Unknown response from agent' from Openshift rhc port-forward

Tags: ruby, openshift, portforwarding, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to run Openshift's rhc port forward command as following:

```
rhc port-forward -a ligatures -n dawningstreams
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Checking available ports ...
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:81:in `negotiate!': unknown response from agent: 1, "\x00\x00\x00-\x01\x00\x00\x00(SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.7.0 i386-mingw32" (Net::SSH::Authentication::AgentError)
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:48:in `connect'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:178:in `agent'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:102:in `each_identity'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:78:in `block in authenticate'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `each'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:65:in `authenticate'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:204:in `start'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/lib/rhc/commands/port_forward.rb:85:in `run'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:294:in `execute'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:285:in `block (3 levels) in to_commander'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.2/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.2/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.2/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.2/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/lib/rhc/command_runner.rb:72:in `run!'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.2/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:37:in `start'
  from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhc-1.27.4/bin/rhc:20:in `<top(required)>'
  from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
  from C:/Ruby193/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

I have already performed `gem update rhc`, but it did not help.

What is this issue and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Openshift IRC chat, we determined that it could be related to a [known issue](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/267561-agenterror-unknown-response-from-agent-on-windows-with-64-bit-putty) solved on a more recent version of `net-ssh`.

Since my Ruby installation was old, I removed it completely and re-installed it (and reinstalled rhc too). The issue is now gone.